# How to get value from outside on HTML?

Tags: html

I want to get value from outside for progress. But it's not working.

```html
<form oninput="y.value=parseInt(height.value)">
  Yaşınız:<input type="text" name="age"><br> 
  Boyunuz: <input type="range" name="height" min="150" max="230">
  <output onchange="bar.value=parseInt(y.value)" name="y"></output>cm <br>
  <progress name="bar" max="230"></progress>
</form>
```

Comment: How would this work? Via some kind of server framework or wishful thinking?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm sorry, but your question is very very unclear. What do you mean by *from outside*??

Comment: I want to forge a link between progress and range. For example range value = 120, progress value = 120

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant this?

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("input", function() {
  var val = parseInt(this.height.value);
  this.y.value = val;
  document.getElementById("bar").value = val;
});
var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
document.getElementById("y").value = height
document.getElementById("bar").value = height
```

```html
<form>
  Yaşınız:<input type="text" name="age"><br/> 
  Boyunuz: <input type="range" name="height" id="height" min="150" max="230">
  <output name="y" id="y"></output>cm<br/>
  <progress name="bar" id="bar" max="230"></progress>
</form>
```